# Can't unbind link from click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to disable all links in a div while a form is shown to force interaction with the form. All, but the Save and Cancel Button belonging to the form. After reading the related posts here for a while I thought it would work with this code. But somehow only the Save-Button works, even without unbinding it. I can't figure out how that makes sense so I guess I am missing something important. Is it possible to unbind a single link from an event listener set up to many events?

```
// set up click event to all links in panel-body 
$('.panel-body a').on('click.myDisable', function() { return false; });
// unbind cancel button
$("li#122.tag-edit-cancel-button").off('click.myDisable');
// show form
$("li#122-form").css('display','block');
// hide list entry
$("li#122").hide();

// save button
$("li#122-form .tag-edit-save-button")
        .click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#edit_tag_122").submit();    
                $('.panel-body a').off('click.myDisable');
            });

// cancel button
$("li#122 .tag-edit-cancel-button")
        .click(function(d) {
                d.preventDefault();
                $("li#122-form").css('display','none');
                $("li#122").show();
                $('.panel-body a').off('click.myDisable');
            });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <ul class='tags tags-class5'>
    <li id="114-form" style="display:none;"> 
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/1/tags/114"  class="edit_tag" data-remote="true" id="edit_tag_114" method="post">
          <div style="display:none">
            <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;"/>
            <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch" />
          </div>
            <input class="tag-edit-input form-control" id="tag_name" name="tag[name]" type="text" value="aslkasdasd" />
        </form>   
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-6 tag-button-row'>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm tag-edit-save-button" href="#">Save</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm tag-edit-cancel-button" href="#">Cancel</a>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li id="114"> 
      <div class='col-md-6 textoverflow left list_1'> sometext </div>
      <div class='col-md-6 tag-button-row'>
        <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm tag-edit-button" data-remote="true" href="/users/1/tags/114/edit">Edit</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-confirm="Delete Tag (it will be deleted from all associated Vocabs?" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" href="/users/1/tags/114" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If more info is needed please let me know. Thx!

Comment: I presume this is being run through ASP.NET, in which case please show the RENDERED code, not the original source

Comment: It's run through Rails. The only thing that will change by rendering is that the Id of the respective tag will be shown instead of <%=(@tag.id)%>. This part should be right though.

Comment: @Flip The Rendered code is preferable as we can then place it into something like JSFiddle, it's unlikely anyone is going to sit and replace those <% %> tags just to help you.

Comment: That makes sense. I will replace them.

Comment: Any chance you could post the HTML as well? It'd be useful to know whether your Save and Cancel buttons are actual buttons, or whether they're links too.

Comment: please put all code's in jsfiddle.net + html

Comment: @Ian Oxley: I updated the post with the HTML code.